# How to add shadow to vector path?

Tags: android, vector, path, drawable

How can I add shadow with blur to an image in vector?
I use the path

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:width="1580dp"
android:height="3340dp"
android:viewportWidth="1580"
android:viewportHeight="3340">

<path
    android:name="@string/frame_frame"
    android:fillColor="#424242"
    android:pathData="M1450,50H130A100.11,100.11,0,0,0,30,150V3190a100.11,100.11,0,0,0,100,100H1450a100.11,100.11,0,0,0,100-100V150A100.11,100.11,0,0,0,1450,50Zm60,3040a60,60,0,0,1-60,60H130a60,60,0,0,1-60-60V250a60,60,0,0,1,60-60H1450a60,60,0,0,1,60,60Z" />
```

[I have to put the shadow on this model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EgDjc.png)

Answer (score 0):

you can not give shadow to vector, you need to give elevation property of specif view where you use this vector file :

Comment: I added an image to the post above

Comment: but vector file you can not add shadow because its is a child view of any other view

Comment: is there an option to add shadow? in java?